# How to dynamically add two v-text-fields to a form when a button is clicked and uniquely identify them

Tags: forms, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I've seen some posts about how to dynamically add test fields to a form when a button is clicked. like in this post [How to add two v-text-fields when I click a button dynamically using vuetify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60939821/how-to-add-two-v-text-fields-when-i-click-a-button-dynamically-using-vuetify) Im not understanding where I would put the v-for in this scenario.

But, how can I achieve this using nuxt2 and vue2. I use a vuex store for the input data, but how can I identify the new text fields being added so I can update the store accordingly?

Ideally I'd have a v-row with 2 v-cols and when I click the button, another row appears with the 2 v-cols, but  Im not understanding where I would put the v-for in this scenario. Small snippet based on the above linked question.

```html
<template>
 <v-card>
  <v-card-text>
   <v-row>
    <v-col>
     <v-text-field
       :label="textField.label1"
       v-model="textField.value1"
      ></v-text-field> Im not understanding where I would put the v-for in this scenario.
      <v-text-field
       :label="textField.label2"
       v-model="textField.value2"
      ></v-text-field>
     </v-col>
     <v-col>
      <v-btn @click="addRow">Add Row</v-btn>
     </v-col>
    </v-row>
   </v-card-text>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Comment: if you want the button to always add another row matching exactly the row you already have, then the v-for can go on the `<v-row>` element.  every loop of the v-for will repeat the element it's on including all children.  you can use the index of the v-for to identify specific rows as needed elsewhere in your code.  see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52530434/use-v-model-inside-a-v-for-loop) as an example.